# Display custom post type as related post using woocommerce product tags

Tags: php, loops, woocommerce

I'm building a woocommerce theme from scratch and I'm trying to figure out how I can display a custom post type using product tags. For example I have apple as a product and I use the word ***apple*** as a product tag.

I have then a custom post type called **recipes**. Let just say I  publish a post called ***apple salad*** then I tag it with the word ***apple*** also.

I want to display the custom post type(**recipes**) based on the woocommerce product tag. If there are any product tags with the word apple under the recipes custom post type it will then be display. I have this code that is under work in progress and still trying to figure out which parts to change. I'm not very fluent with PHP and I have been researching for any post that is similar to my problem

```
<?php //Related Post by Tag
    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

                  if ( $tags ) {
                  $first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;

                          $args = array(
                                'tag__in' => array( $first_tag ),
                                'post_type' => 'recipes',
                          );

                          }

                  $related_post = new WP_Query( $args );
                  if( $related_post->have_posts() ) : while ( $related_post->have_posts() ) : $related_post->the_post();

                            ?>

                  <div class="full-width related-post">
                      <span>Recommended</span>
                      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                  </div>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>


    <?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```